# C#/C++ X509Certificate2.Verify fails OCSP when IE uses authenticating proxy

Tags: c#, c++, cryptography, x509certificate, mscapi

I am attempting to validate a certificate using X509Certificate2.Verify() (and/or it's C++/CAPI equivalent).

The issue is that when Internet Explorer's connection settings specify a proxy which requires authentication, the OCSP check will always fail (the OS can't check that the certificate hasn't been revoked, since it doesn't have credentials to pass through the proxy.)

Microsoft has a KB similar to this, but doesn't really offer any sort of a fix.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915787

Even if I have the credentials (username and password), I am unable to pass them to the cryptography API (in either .NET or native).

Is there a solution which allows certificates to be validated even when there is an system default proxy which enforces authentication?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Some indications from Microsoft that this is simply impossible:

"CryptoAPI also may not be able to authenticate to a proxy or to caching servers that require basic authentication to reach the HTTP URL that refers to the CRL distribution point."
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457027.aspx#EFAA

"Authentication to proxy servers that do not use Windows Integrated Authentication in certain programs may be unsuccessful. This issue occurs because the Winhttp.dll process is designed for use by non-interactive services and does not prompt the user for network credentials."
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/887196

Comment: Google also has the same problem with CAPI: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5313